# Rigid and flexible ZIF-8 framework

Tags: molecular-dynamics

What are the differences in parameters in the force field for MD simulation study of **RIGID** and **FLEXIBLE** ZIF-8 framework?Is the electrostatic interaction term present in the rigid one?

Comment: What is ZIF-8??